# How to output a message with an It assertion in MSpec

Tags: unit-testing, assert, mspec

We're using [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) for unit tests after having previously used MbUnit.

I'm used to being able to say

```
Assert.IsTrue(status, "Status should be true");
```

in MbUnit, i.e. adding a message to the assertion which is output if it fails.

I can't find any corresponding functionality in MSpec. I'm testing that some XML validates and, if it fails, I want to report the validation error message. So my MSpec code looks like

```
string message;

bool isValid = ValidateXml(myXml, out message);

isValid.ShouldBeTrue();
```

But I want to be able to add the `message` to the test output if the `ShouldBeTrue()` fails.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source for MSpec, no. The extension methods do not take a string parameter for a message.

You could trivially add the functionality yourself, in terms of code to write; the code is in `machine.specifications / Source / Machine.Specifications / ExtensionMethods.cs`. I don't know how hard it is to build.

For example you could create overloads of `ShouldBeFalse` and `ShouldBeTrue` like so:

```
[AssertionMethod]
public static void ShouldBeFalse([AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_FALSE)] this bool condition, string message)
{
  if (condition)
    throw new SpecificationException(message);
}

[AssertionMethod]
public static void ShouldBeTrue([AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_TRUE)] this bool condition, string message)
{
  if (!condition)
    throw new SpecificationException(message);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for that, I've used that code to write a new extension method which throws a `SpecificationException` with the custom message. If you want to add something about that to your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no infrastructure for this at the moment, but like Matt I would suggest implementing your own "reporting" assertions on top of MSpec's built-in assertion library (possibly in a `<Product>.ForTesting` class library).

In all other cases, the `It` field tells what should be observable, hence the missing message parameter.